# Форматирование текста

Tags: php, html, база-данных, mysql

Если в базе данных хранится много текста, то как сделать, чтобы на страницу выводилось только первые 10 символов одной строчкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функциями substr и strlen Вы можете воспользоваться для "обрезания" текста в php. Но можно сделать эффективнее. Используйте запрос базы вида

```
select left(text_column_index, 10) from table_name where ...
```

На выходе Вы получите первые десять символов текста для каждой записи.

Кроме того (сам столкнулся) в php у вас могут возникнуть трудности при "обрезании" русского (unicode, utf-8) текста. MySQL таких проблем вроде не испытывает...

Comment: В php использовать для этого нужно функции mb_*. Например: mb_substr($text, $start, $length, $from_enc, $to_enc);

Answer (score 2):

В SQL запросе можно указывать, с какой и сколько позиций прислать в ответ :

```
mysql_qeury("SELECT * FROM tableololo WHERE var1='param1' LIMIT 10, 10");
```

Происходит выборка и установка, что нужно показать с 10-й строчки результата по 20-ую(10+10).

Answer (score 1):

См. функции [substr](http://www.php.su/functions/?substr) и [strlen](http://www.php.su/functions/?strlen)